# How to invoke a method in a service class with @transactional and @service annotation by reflection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, reflection

First, forgive my poor English, I am just working hard on my English:).

I'm trying to find an easy way to set the communication more simple between front-end and back-end, because I use ActiveMQ as the Message Oriented Middleware. So XML string became the request carrier.

For example, front-end send a string request to back-end including package name, class name, method name and parameters list, in this way, back-end is allowed to invoke the correct method by these information, and send invoke result back to front-end. It works, but not perfect. The problem is that when I tried to invoke a method in a service class with `@Transational` and `@Service` annotation(which is the common practice to connect to the database),the transaction seemed not being opened, request and response are both received, just left a lot of sleeping connection in mysql database process, as much as the ActiveMQ's consumers every time.

[image]

Target method in service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO udao;

    public User getUserByName(String username) {
        return udao.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Invoke method(some code has been omitted):

```
@Component
public class ReflectTool {
    public Object invokeMethod(String packageName,String className,String methodName,List paramList) {
        BeanFactory beanFactory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Object obj = beanFactory.getBean(packageName+"."+className);
        Class cla = obj.getClass();
        Method method = findMethod(Class cla,String methodName);
        return method.invoke(obj, params);
    }
}
```

I've searched a lot answer, but none of them worked. Like:use a proxy object to invoke but not the target object, cause spring framework has used a proxy class instead the service class with `@Transactional` annotation to help we manager the transaction, but the code (`AopUtils.isAopProxy(obj)`) returns `true`, so it mean the object is exactly a proxy object which I got from the spring context? I'm not very familiar with Dynamic Agent Model.

Thanks for your attention, please tell me if I did something wrong.

Comment: Your `ReflectTool` is a horrible code smell. The usual practice is to call your `UserService` from other Spring beans. Why aren't you doing this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.As you said,it's not a common way,but my project flow likes 'front-end-->ActiveMQ-->back-end',back-end listen to a particular queue in ActiveMQ,and take the message from it by front-end send.So I take reflection to complete 'request-response' process,it could reduces the amount of code,and almost did.

Comment: @Transactional only works when you use Spring's proxy stuff (contexts, autowiring beans and the like). If you use reflection and call the method directly, Spring's proxy stuff doesn't get a chance to intercept the call and apply the transactional wrapping.

Comment: Consider using Spring Integration instead; I've used it for exactly this kind of arrangement, where you can identify a named channel (which is far superior to tightly coupling the client to a specific method call).

Comment: I just viewed the Spring Integration's homepage,it looks like a new framework,Maybe it will be helpful,I'll take a time to study it,thanks for your advice.

Comment: The main issue is that you are loading a full application each time you need a bean. Never do things like `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` more then once. That is generally a code smell. What it does is that it creates a new application, including connections to the datasource etc. each time increasing the number of open connections to the database. Instead inject the `ApplicationContext` as your, ugly, `ReflectTool` appears to be already a Spring Managed bean. Nonetheless you generally should n't be doing things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was going to this I'd try the following approach:

DON'T use BeanFactory, inject in your ReflectTool the ApplicationContect: @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext; if the beans you want to recover implements some interface or extends a class then maybe you can replace this injection by a Map. Spring will make it work

Try to get the object of the bean you need.

the lines you have regarding the capture of the method and execution should work since it is an bean calling another bean.

Hope this helps. I had a similar situation where I needed to invoke a @Transactional method and I fixed in a similar way I have described.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,BeanFactory seems to be the culprit,I've debugged my code for many times,and I found that these sleeping connection increased after code- new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("") was runned.So I moved this line to a new method like getContext(),once the beanFactory is needed,this method will be called and return the beanFactory,though databases's connection still will increase,just one or two.
@Autowired seems to be a better practice,I'll take it to my code tomorrow,hope it will be useful.